# AzureDevOps pipeline and sqlpackage

Tags: sql-server, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

All,

I would like to create a DACPAC file containing the Schema of the target database during the CI process. I can use this as a baseline schema to create a Testbed against which I can test the scripts in the release.

```
SqlPackage.exe /TargetFile:"C:\AzureDevOps\AdventureWorks.dacpac" /Action:Extract /SourceServerName:"SQL2016" /SourceDatabaseName:"AdventureWorks2016"

SqlPackage.exe /SourceFile:"C:\AzureDevOps\AdventureWorks.dacpac" /Action:Publish /TargetServerName:"SQL2016" /TargetDatabaseName:"AdWorks"
```

I can use the above scripts to create the DACPAC and then deploy the DACPAC to create the testbed.

I don't know how to incorporate this step in the AzureDevOps pipeline. I searched for the `sqlpackage` task but I could not find it.

[*Perform SQL server actions in Azure Pipelines or TFS*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/sql-server-actions?view=vsts)

Can others throw some light on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SqlPackage executable needs to be installed in the Agent Machine inorder to execute the SqlPackage command. I'm not sure that HostedAgent having this Executable. So I'd recommend by creating our own Agent, where the Sqlpackage is installed. Then you can execute the scripts in AzureDevOps using your own Agent.

If you are using `Azure SQL Database` there is a [default task available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-azure-dacpac-deployment?view=vsts), where you can easily deploy the DACPAC file

[image]

Comment: Can you give me some more info on this? I will readup and take it up with vsts admin. 
<<So I'd recommend by creating our own Agent, where the Sqlpackage is installed>>

For me deploying comes later, I need to first extract the schema inorder to create the dacpac.

Comment: @GopinathRajee Sure, please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts) on how to install an Agent in Windows machine(or)any other platform. I think your VSTS admin knows how to deploy a new agent in a machine.Let me know if you need any information

Comment: I was thinking, if there is a way to compare the repo against the basline dacpac and generate a diff script then I dont even have to setup the testbed database. I just have to get the diff script and run it against the target environment. Is there a way?

With a dacpac to create the skeletal database I can even use a docker/container to build the testdb and destroy it right after use. Pretty Cool!!